# Using [WHERE, IN, LEN, IN] TSQL

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I am trying to write a simple statement in my where clause but I don't believe I have the syntax right. The query looks to search whether these ID's are in this column but I am not sure if I can use `IN` twice in the same line? Could anyone please provide some feed back. Thanks!

```
WHERE... AND (tableA.ColumnA in LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(TableB.ColumnB))) in (5,7) )
```

I am getting some syntax errors near the second `IN` and can't figure out if this is the correct way to approach this?

Comment: What is the purpose of `LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(TableB.ColumnB)))`? And what column do you mean when you say "whether these ID's are in this column"?

Comment: I am trimming white space for both columns. I have ID's in Column A that are IN column B. So the point of this Where clause is that, when a user chooses the main Person parameter, the query will look in my Financial table and pull all IDs  (associated with that Person) that are also in the main Business table. Essentially, `tableA.columnA in tableb.columnB`. But, i only want 5 character and 7 character IDs. Does this help clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use IN with a column, it needs to be a sub-select, but here is a correct way you can do it (Wes's sub-select still has the same syntax error):

```
WHERE... AND (tableA.ColumnA in (
 SELECT ColumnB FROM TableB WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(TableB.ColumnB))) in (5,7) 
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a subquery instead.

```
WHERE... AND (SELECT TA.ColumnA 
              FROM TableA TA 
              WHERE TA.ColumnA IN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(TABLEB.ColumnB))) IN (5,7)
```

Comment: I tried this but I believe I received the same error. Here is what my code looks like with an error by the second `in`. "Incorrect syntax near 'in" :/

`AND 
   (mainfilters.RPCO IN ( LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ABC6.CU))) IN (5,7)))`

Answer (score 0):

using join

```
 join TableB 
   on TableB.ColumnB = tableA.ColumnA   
  and LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(TableB.ColumnB))) in (5,7)
```